# Using Strings for File Location Reference with System.getProperty("user.home")

Tags: java, file

I am trying to generate a folder on the desktop named the current date, and then generate another folder within current date folder names "IBA". Simply a folder on the desktop and then a folder within the generated desktop folder.. I am having a little issue with syntax for doing this is java.

I. A string that is today's date. **(works)**

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());
```

II. A file that finds the users desktop folder. **(works)**

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
```

III. A file that finds the users desktop folder then finds a folder within the desktop folder named today's date using the above string, and adds a folder called "IBA". **(error)**

```
File desktopdate = new File(desktop/date, "IBA");
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) File, String
at DateFolder.main(DateFolder.java:11)

Here is the full code for reference. I think this would be helpful for others because it would show how to use strings for file location references after System.getProperty("user.home").

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateFolder {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());
    File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
    File desktopdate = new File(desktop/date, "Desktop");

    File dateFolder = null;
    do {
       dateFolder = new File(desktop, date);
    } 
    while (dateFolder.exists());

    if (!dateFolder.mkdirs()) {
        System.err.println("Unable to create folder \"dateFolder\". " + dateFolder);
    }


    File Food = null;
    do {
       Food = new File(desktopdate,"Food");
    } 
    while (Food.exists());

    if (!Food.mkdirs()) {
        System.err.println("Unable to create folder \"dateFolder\". " + dateFolder);
    }   
}
}
```

[This is an example of what I would like to happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPJFX.png)

Thank you all for your time and community contribution.

Comment: [How to combine paths in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/412380)

Comment: You're trying to divide a file by a string.... What do you actually intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators are not overrided in Java so you need to use the objects, replace:

```
File desktopdate = new File(desktop/date, "Desktop");
```

For:

```
File desktopdate = new File(new File(desktop, date), "IBA");
```

Since the constructor (File f, String s) gets a File s (may be a directory) in the folder f

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. You have answered my question.

Comment: So accept as correct and/or upvote if it helped you.